# mongoDB, mongoose, cannot connect to DB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

First time using mongoDB. Trying to connect to my cluster that i just created on atlas however i keep getting errors

```
keys.jss

module.exports = {
    mongoURI: 'mongodb+srv://john:<********>@mern-shopping-i5abd.mongodb.net/testretryWrites=true&w=majority'
};
```

I might be following an outdated tutorial so certain things might be 'unnecessary'

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
    .connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true} )
    .then(() => console.log('monogoDB Connected...'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server started on port ${port}'));
```

Rather than displaying port '5000' i would get an error (different each time)

- message: '3rd parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` must be a function, got "object"',
  name: 'MongooseError'

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: how do i check which version i am using? i did npm install to get all the files

Comment: Also, body-parser is included in express now. No need to manually require it :).  It may also make sense to put your `app.listen(...)` inside of the callback to your DB connection. That way you know the DB is connected to before the app starts.

Comment: It should be in your `package.json`, under the `dependencies` object

Comment: mongoose@5.9.4 is the version im using

Comment: If you `console.log` or debug, what's the value of `db`? Make sure it's the correct value

Comment: Even as I am looking at the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html), you appear to be using the `connect` method correctly. what happens if you replace the `.then` and `catch` with a function callback as the 3rd parameter?

Comment: DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Comment: Looks like the connected then!

Comment: does that mean its connected successfully? shouldnt it also display 'port 5000 and connected' message. what is the deprecationwarning that i got?

Comment: That is a message from the server itself. To get rid of the deprecation warning, update your 2nd parameter in `connect` to: `{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}`. Yes, it should display the `console.log` that you have there.

Comment: Thank you so much. that seems to get rid of the deprecation warning. one quick question in the terminal it displays this message:
Server started on port ${port}

shouldn't it state:
Server started on port 5000
MongoDB connected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it would look with a function as a callback, instead of using promises. Notice that I also moved the app startup inside the callback function. This ensures that the app only starts up when we successfully connect to the DB.

I also moved the DB options (2nd parameter in the connect method), into a variable. This way, it's easy to find and can be modified in one place, if necessary. Ideally, you'd keep all your DB config in a single file, and reference it in other files as needed. Separate concerns :)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;
const dbOptions = {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true};

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect(db, dbOptions, function(error) {
    // we had an error of some kind
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);

      // better yet, we don't want to app to run without our DB!
      throw error;
    }

    // If we made it here, no errors came up
    console.log('monogoDB Connected...');

    // Start up the app!
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
  });
```

Here is how it would look with the promise structure:

```
const express = require( "express" );
const mongoose = require( "mongoose" );
const bodyParser = require( "body-parser" );

const app = express();

// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use( bodyParser.json() );

// DB config
const db = require( "./config/keys" ).mongoURI;
const dbOptions = {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true};

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect( db, dbOptions )
  .then( () => {
    console.log( "monogoDB Connected..." );

    // Start the application
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    app.listen( port, () => {
      console.log( `Server started on port ${port}` );
    } );
  } )
  .catch( err => {
    console.log( err );
    throw err;
  } );
```

Comment: I updated the answer just befpore you posted this ;)

Comment: MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: bad auth Authentication failed. What does this mean

Comment: This means that the username and password combination provided is not correct

Comment: Fantastic! worked like a charm and i understand this section better now. thank you

Comment: @JMoss Glad it worked! Be sure to mark the answer correct if it solved the issue